# How to get the revision number from a svn tag using groovy

Tags: svn, groovy, sed

Does any one know how can i extract the revision number using groovy from a svn tag

-r revision http://svn/....

output : revision

is there a equivalent of sed in groovy or something?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can run a Groovy script, using the `GString.execute()` method to accomplish this:

```
def url = "http://your.subversion.url/svn/YourRepository"
println "svn info --show-item last-changed-revision $url".execute().text
```

Which will print out the latest revision number for that SVN path.

Comment: Thanks will try it out